# Xcode 4 : Opening brace on the same line

Tags: xcode4

I just installed Xcode 4 and the opening brace of the auto generated functions is on a new line.

For example :

```
- (void)dealloc
{
  [_window release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

I'd like to have the opening brace on the same line like it was in Xcode 3 :

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [_window release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Can someone help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MarkC's answer has the right idea, but <Jedi> these aren't the templates you're looking for </Jedi>.

The templates you need to edit are in either

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates
```

or

```
/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates
```

depending on which platform you're targeting.

Answer (score 3):

Don't edit those templates directly! Apple usually automatically deletes them when you upgrade to next version of Xcode...

Instead, you want to copy/paste them into:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/
```

e.g.:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/File Templates/
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Project Templates/
```

...and then edit them there. Xcode knows it should look there for your custom versions, and Apple will leave the contents of your home directory alone.

Comment: I've done this, but now everything appears twice in the Xcode "New file" sheet.

Comment: I believe you can delete the originals if you like - do a cut/paste (move) instead of a copy/paste). Most people just rename the directories, thereby causing them to come up with a different name.

Comment: NB: until this year, Apple allowed us to put our templates in a separate top-level section, with a custom name. Then they removed that feature when they made Xcode4. If you want it back (I think everyone does? It was useful!), send a bug report to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

All the template code that XCode 4 uses to create new class files is in 
/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File\ Templates/Cocoa/Objective-C\ class.xctemplate

Just edit those templates to suit your coding style and you are good to go.

Comment: I modified all the .m files but it didn't change anything. I still have the brace on a new line when I create a new class, project, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an application called Snippet Edit that allows you to easily edit all of the supplied code snippets. You will need to be using Xcode v4.3 or later though if you wish to use it.

The application can be found at http://cocoaholic.com/snippet_edit/