# Is there a way to change bracket placement and indentation in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I want to change the default behavior of XCode (4) for aligning brackets from this:

```
- (BOOL)someValue {
    return _someValue;
}
```

To this:

```
- (BOOL)someValue
{
    return _someValue;
}
```

I've reviewed the docs here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/100-Xcode_User_Defaults/UserDefaultRef.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005535-CH3-SW57

But I still dont' understand how to make the change.  Any help?

Comment: it's written like that in the code snippet section, but if you click on the edit button, every thing is greyed out so it can't be change.

Comment: There should be a way to edit it similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218729/is-it-possible-to-change-the-way-xcode-indents-comment-blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the [documentation you referred to is for XCode 3.1](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/000-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005535-CH1-SW1) (I've linked the introduction page which says so clearly). Judging by the number of comments on devforums.apple.com about this, I think the XCCodeSenseFormattingOptions key no longer exists under the new XCode4 defaults (which are stored under bundle ID `com.apple.dt.XCode`). If you want this particular feature restored, [file a bug with Apple](http://bugreporter.apple.com).

Secondly, you might be able to do what you're looking for by modifying templates. I discovered [this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286398/xcode-4-opening-brace-on-the-same-line), but there's no tacit confirmation there that the suggestion actually succeeded.

Comment: I gave a presentation on this a few months ago - you might find it useful if you want to customise your templates http://lanyrd.com/2011/lidg28/sffpf/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an application called Snippet Edit that allows you to easily edit all of the supplied code snippets. You will need to be using Xcode v4.3 or later though if you wish to use it.

The application can be found at http://cocoaholic.com/snippet_edit/